# Variadic Template Parameter Packs with Alternating Types

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I was wondering if it is possible to capture an alternating parameter pattern using a parameter pack.  For example,

```
template<typename T, size_t U, typename... Args>
class foo<T, U, Args...>
{
   public:
     foo() : my_T(nullptr), my_U(U) {}

   private:
     T* my_T;
     size_t my_U;
     foo<Args...> my_next_foo;
}
```

So this doesn't work since Args is a parameter pack of only types.  Is there a way to modify this so that the typename T, size_t U pattern can be properly captured in a variadic template?  Thanks

Comment: Yeah. Take pairs of a type and a value as a type list.

Comment: and in general (when your pattern is non-repeating), the common way to transfer non-type arguments is by putting them inside a class. Examples include `std::true_type`, `std::integral_constant`, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values as template parameters are second class citizens, in my experience.

Upgrade them to first class with an alias:

```
template<std::size_t n>
using size = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, n>;
```

then pattern match:

```
template<class...>
struct foo;
template<>
struct foo<> {
  // empty
};
template<class T, size_t U, typename... Args>
struct foo<T, size<U>, Args...> {
  foo() : my_T(nullptr), my_U(U) {}

private:
  T* my_T;
  size_t my_U;
  foo<Args...> my_next_foo;
};
```

and bob is your uncle.

Note, however, that taking `U` as a template parameter, then storing it as a run time value, is highly questionable.

Users of `foo` must do:

```
foo< Chicken, size<3>, Dog, size<17> >
```

instead of

```
foo< Chicken, 3, Dog, 17 >
```

Comment: This seems like the best option so far.  One question, what would be the pitfall of storing the template parameter for use during runtime?

Comment: @armstrhu you can access them at runtime without storing them.  `enum {my_U=U};` lets you access the compile-time value of `U` from the type `foo<?>` relatively easily.  The reason why it is a bad sign is that if you have a value that varies at run time, why not pass it in as a run time value, instead of encoding it in the type?

Comment: ahh, yeah good point.  So you are correct, for my application I don't actually need to store the value of U, just access it.  I guess in my little example above I didn't fully think that through.  Basically, I am building a variadic template over a set of std::array's and I was trying to figure out how one could pass the array type and length.  So really, my T* is actually an std::array<T,U>* and there would be no size_t U variable.  Your solution should solve my problem regardless.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just write your own pair:

```
template <typename T, size_t U>
struct foo_pair { };
```

And have a pack of those:

```
template<typename T, size_t U, typename... Pairs>
class foo<foo_pair<T, U>, Pairs...> {
    ...
};
```

Which would be instantiated like:

```
foo<foo_pair<int, 4>, foo_pair<char, 17>, ...> f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `Args` to `foo` as an `std::tuple`.  Use `std::integral_constant` for `U` instead of passing an integral constant as a template parameter to the `std::tuple`.  Then the `Args` parameters pack contains all the pairs of types and sizes.

For example, when instantiating foo you would do so with a type like this:

```
Foo<std::tuple<int, std::integral_constant<size_t, 5> >,
    std::tuple<char, std::integral_constant<size_t, 3> > >
```

When implementing `foo`, you should pass your parameter pack to another `std::tuple` and use `std::tuple_element` to select the Nth element of the tuple.

This is just one possible approach, you may find it easier to implement `foo` if you use type lists.

Comment: A problem with `tuple` this way is that it is a large, complex class, in order for instances to be optimal at run time.  Using it as nothing more than a way to pack together types can cause the compiler to get creaky, needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You might create a class representing the data container `T* my_T` with `size_t my_U`. Having that, you can implement your template:

```
#include <array>

using std::size_t;

template<typename... Args>
struct foo;

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct foo<std::array<T, N>>
{
    std::array<T, N> array;
};

template<typename T, size_t N, typename... Args>
struct foo<std::array<T, N>, Args...>
{
    std::array<T, N> array;
    foo<Args...> next_array;
};

int main() {
    foo<std::array<char, 1>, std::array<short, 2>, std::array<int, 4>> foos;
}
```

Note: I am using std::array as an replacement for the data container.